# Total Discount In Minicart Magento 2. Plugin is ready but how can I display it?

Tags: magento2

Trying to do like this:

[image]

I've created a Plugin, but where minicart template is placed? And how can I display the discount via knockout? Thank you.

**app/code/Vendor/Checkout/Plugin/Cart.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Checkout\Plugin;

class Cart
{
    protected $checkoutSession;
    protected $checkoutHelper;
    protected $quote;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->checkoutHelper = $checkoutHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Get active quote
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    protected function getQuote()
    {
        if (null === $this->quote) {
            $this->quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        }
        return $this->quote;
    }

    protected function getDiscountAmount()
    {
        $discountAmount = 0;
        foreach($this->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
            $discountAmount += ($item->getDiscountAmount() ? $item->getDiscountAmount() : 0);
        }
        return $discountAmount;
    }

    public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject, $result)
    {
        $result['discount_amount_no_html'] = -$this->getDiscountAmount();
        $result['discount_amount'] = $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice(-$this->getDiscountAmount());

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: in minicart where you want to display discount ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create below files to display discount in minicart
**app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_total_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="total" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/minicart/totals</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="total.discount-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/minicart/total/discount-total</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

> **app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/totals.html**

```
<!-- ko foreach: elems -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

> **app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/total/discount-total.html**

```
<div class="discount-total">
<span class="label">
    <!-- ko i18n: 'Discount Total :' --><!-- /ko -->
</span>
<div class="amount">
    <span class="price-wrapper" data-bind="html: cart().discount_amount"></span>
</div>
```

Please check below screen shot of output i have fetched grand-total for demo.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I receive data from my plugin but it returns 0 USD for me... Strange...

Comment: What could be wrong with it?

Comment: Try to add static value if it comes then there may be a something wrong with plugin data fetching

Comment: As per your plugin code it seems that there is some extra character in function  before this $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice(-$this->getDiscountAmount()); corrected value code is $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->getDiscountAmount());

Comment: Thank you Harsh!

Comment: Your welcome @Aleksey